# Scrapy scraping the follow-up page of a scraped item

Tags: python, scrapy

I am building a simple scraper and I have a list of items I want to scrape. I use the following code and it all works fine.

```
import scrapy
from tutsplus.items import TutsplusItem
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class CodeTutorialSpider(CrawlSpider):

    # Configuration
    name = "tutspluscoding"
    allowed_domains = ["code.tutsplus.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://code.tutsplus.com/courses?page=1"]
    rules = [
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('code\.tutsplus\.com\/courses\?page\=\d+')), callback='parse_items', follow=True)
    ]

    # Parse tutorials
    def parse_items(self, response):
        tuts = response.xpath("//html/body/div[2]/main/div[3]/ul/li")
        print "Tutorials found: "+str(len(tuts))
        items = []
        for tut in tuts:
            item = TutsplusItem()
            item['title']     = tut.xpath("a[1]/text()").extract()
            item['link']      = tut.xpath("div[1]/a/@href").extract()
            items.append(item)
        return items
```

Now what I want the scraper to do is follow the link it scrapes, grab the first 100 words of the intro text and then save the item.

I have tried several things but none of them worked and I also couldn't find anything on the subject. So if anyone knows how to accomplish what I've described with Scrapy please share.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What part is not working? Also you xpath is a little fragile, try to use classes, id's etc.. to find what you want

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The code I posted is working just fine. I am wondering how I can scrape the follow up page (which is the link attribute of the TutsplusItem I have already scraped). So I want to have an additional attribute called "intro" which is located on the view page. So my question is: how do i follow that link, scrape that part of the page I'm interested in and then save it on the original item, yield it and move on to the next.

Comment: So you want to scrape `tut.xpath("div[1]/a/@href").extract()`? If so what do you want from the page?

Comment: You should also be aware that your code does not seem to work, tuts[0] is the page you are already on. That and if you want to visit all pages you need to deal with the pagination

Comment: Yes exactly! I want to extract the a part (or all of the text in a specific div). So i want to the bot to follow up on the URL and then scrape a specific div and extract the text from it. This is a simplified version of the current state of the scraper. But I just can't figure out how to make the scraper go to the second page for each list item and extract/add the information that isn't available on the list item overview page.